# Amcharts place labels at certain x y position

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I'm trying to place some label in certain x,y position inside an AmCharts xy chart.

Here's my code that add labels:

```
var firstChart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", config);
var i1x = firstChart.xAxes[0].getCoordinate(parseFloat(data[0].i1x));
var i1y = firstChart.yAxes[0].getCoordinate(parseFloat(data[0].i1y));        
var i2x = firstChart.xAxes[0].getCoordinate(parseFloat(data[0].i2x));
var i2y = firstChart.yAxes[0].getCoordinate(parseFloat(data[0].i2y));
var iMainx = firstChart.xAxes[0].getCoordinate(parseFloat(data[0].iMainx));
var iMainy = firstChart.yAxes[0].getCoordinate(parseFloat(data[0].iMainy));
var i4x = firstChart.xAxes[0].getCoordinate(parseFloat(data[0].i4x));
var i4y = firstChart.yAxes[0].getCoordinate(parseFloat(data[0].i4y));
var i5x = firstChart.xAxes[0].getCoordinate(parseFloat(data[0].i5x));
var i5y = firstChart.yAxes[0].getCoordinate(parseFloat(data[0].i5y));

firstChart.addLabel(i1x, i1y, 'rpm', 'center', 16, 'black', 0, 1, true);
firstChart.addLabel(i2x, i2y, 'rpm', 'center', 16, 'black', 0, 1, true);
firstChart.addLabel(iMainx, iMainy, 'rpm', 'center', 16, 'black', 0, 1, true);
firstChart.addLabel(i4x, i4y, 'rpm', 'center', 16, 'black', 0, 1, true);
firstChart.addLabel(i5x, i5y, 'rpm', 'center', 16, 'black', 0, 1, true);
```

The problem is that i have all the Y points that are ok but the X axis is not, all the labels shouls stay on the left of the graph.

Here a screenshot[image]

Answer (score 0):

The issue involves the use of `center`, which doesn't quite work correctly. If you want to center-align text, try `middle`, which will also place the labels correctly to the left as desired.

I also highly recommend against using undocumented properties - `xAxes` and `yAxes` are internal properties that are managed by the library itself. If an update is released that changes how those properties are managed, your code may break. Use the `valueAxes` array instead, which is documented, and reference the desired axis by index from your config.

[Demo using `middle`](https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/0066f3be64f5c62b3258865f9a960654?editors=0010)